# Reading a cache file previously written by the same app

Tags: android, android-file

I'm writing to a file using the code below:

```
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "cachefile");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
StringBuilder cachetext = new StringBuilder();
Iterator bri = brands.iterator();
Iterator bli = brand_id.iterator();
while(bli.hasNext()) {
    cachetext.append(bli.next() + "|" + bri.next() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
fos.write(cachetext.toString().getBytes());
fos.close();
```

This works fine - no errors and the file ends up containing what I expect it to contain. When I go to read it via openFileInput(), however, I get an exception telling me that path separators are not allowed

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(getCacheDir() + "/cachefile");
```

Fair enough, that contains a slash, but how else can I specify the path of the file I want to open? There must be a way to do this, of course, but I can't find answers via Google ('read', 'cache' and 'file' not being the most niche of terms ...) so I thought I'd try the human touch. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your problem is that [getCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) returns **File**, not a **String**?

Answer (score 11):

you do it pretty much the same way you created the output file:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "cachefile"));
```

Comment: The important change here is the use of **`new FileInputStream`** instead of `openFileInput`. 

`openFileInput` allow you to acces local app files in /data/data/com.myapp/files/ and cache is located in /data/data/com.myapp/cache/