# Android not creating/appending a.txt file

Tags: android, file

This is what doing to read from a .txt file in my android activity. Though the app runs, I find that no file is created/appended. In logcat following line is shown,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/Desktop/RiaC_android/Test/app/src/main/assets/SampleFile.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The code I'm currently using, though I have tried before,
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("test_File.txt"));
however, the result remains same.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
File testFile = new File("/home/Desktop/RiaC_android/Test/app/src/main/assets", "SampleFile.txt");
FileWriter writer = null;
try {
writer = new FileWriter(testFile, true);
writer.write("Hello File!!");
writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
if (testFile.exists())
tv.setText("File created!!");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
     }
}
```

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What you mean by this /home/Desktop/RiaC_android/Test/app/src/main/assets path?

Comment: did you give WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest.xml

Comment: It is just an address i'm trying to create the file. I'm using this as a testing purpose only. @Anoop M

Comment: Yes I have given the permission. @Vishwajit Palankar

Comment: do you trying to write inside app's asset folder?

Comment: the path is invalid @ree1991

Comment: yes in this case I'm trying to write in the asset folder. But I've also previously tried to read from .txt file which i had already put in the assets folder. But the same fileNotFound exception is shown.

Comment: You can't. The assets folder is read-only at runtime.

Pick a different location to save your data.!

Comment: @Anoop M I've tried different locations too. Even when I try to read from a file in the app's assets folder, the same error is shown. Any more suggestions?

Comment: see my answer #ree1991

Comment: You are trying to create a file on your PC (project asset directory) from Android device. You cant do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write file to assets folder.The assets folder is read-only at runtime. Pick a different location to save your data. ie , Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() don't use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().

**For reading files from asset use the following method**

```
public String readFromAsset(String fileName, Context context) {
StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
InputStream fIn = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;
BufferedReader input = null;
try {
    fIn = context.getResources().getAssets()
            .open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
    input = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = "";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        returnString.append(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
} finally {
    try {
        if (isr != null)
            isr.close();
        if (fIn != null)
            fIn.close();
        if (input != null)
            input.close();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.getMessage();
    }
}
return returnString.toString();
  }
```

Comment: It worked well. Thanks. On a different note, is there no option in Android Studio as not to use only sdCard for storing app data? I mean, as in Eclipse we could use Assets folder to store app data for read AND write purpose.

Comment: According to the updated project structure of android studio asset folder located at /app/src/main.if you couldn't find it.create a folder named 'assets' inside it.we can put our fonts,css etc in asset at project construction time that wasn't mean at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify files in asset folder. just think them readonly files.

If you want to create text file and modify them, create a file using [getExternalCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()) and `new File` method.

```
public static File CreateTextFile(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
    final File root = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    return new File(root, filename);
}
```

**EDIT APPENDED BELOW**

**1. To write text simply, do as below**

```
String text = "bla bla";
FileWriter writer=null;
    try {
            File file = CreateTextFile("something.txt"); // proposed method
            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            writer = new FileWriter(file);

            /** Saving the contents to the file*/
            writer.write(text);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**2. To read cache file,**
Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971667/361100

**3. One more example**
Below example is to write fetched text from internet.

```
String webUrl = "http://www.yourdata.com/data.txt";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(webUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

        urlConnection.connect();
        File file = CreateTextFile("something.txt"); // proposed method

        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
        }

        fileOutput.close();
        if(downloadedSize==totalSize)
            filepath=file.getPath();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        filepath=null;
    }
```

Comment: Using this code I see that the .txt file is saved inside "app/build/intermediates/assets/debug". Now how do I read from it? Can I use the same 'root' to read or append the file numerous times during the application ruuning?

Comment: @ree1991 // you can read/write at any time because it is granted cache directory for that purpose. I edited answer how to read/write file.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't write** to `/asset` directory because it is read-only.

The assets folder is like folders res, src, gen, etc. These are all useful to provide different files as input to build system to generate APK file for your app.

All these are read-only while your app is running. At run-time you can write to SD card.

You do not access `assets/` at runtime using `File`. You access `assets/` at runtime using `AssetManager`, which you can get via `getResources().getAssets()`.

To read from `/asset` folder, use the following code:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("SampleFile.txt");
           if ( inputStream != null)
                Log.d("TAG", "It worked!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();

I'm getting an error as Cannot resolve method getResources()..

Comment: If you want to use it outside your activity then you should pass your Activity context and use that context to call the method.